# how to get Instance in ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I use `StructureMap` for `DI`, set up like this :

```
private static void Ioc()
{
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
    {
        x.For<IUnitOfWork>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<myContext>();
        x.Scan(config =>
        {
            config.AssemblyContainingType<ICityService>();
            config.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
    });
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());
}
```

And I have an `ActionFilterAttribute` in an `ActionFilter` and want to get an instance of an object like this :

```
public Permission(string controllerName)
{
    _uow = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
    _SettingService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISettingService>();
}
```

but when this class run for four or more times, I'm getting this error :

> The operation cannot be completed because the `DbContext` has been disposed.

and I can't continue. If I change these lines:

```
 _uow = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
 _SettingService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISettingService>();
```

and remove the dependency on the container:

```
_uow = new myContext();                           
_SettingService = new SettingService(_uow);
```

everything work fine, but I have problem - the data in `SettingService` is always different because the context is not the same between the instances.